# Is Data Entity Model in .net 3.5 not supported "Stored Procedure Import"?

Tags: .net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Is Data Entity Framework not supported function import in .net 3.5. I have tried a lot to import function but it is not showing in Entity class. In .net 4.0, it is working fine.

Can anyone please tell me that it is supported 3.5 or not.

Answer (score 1):

From here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

> **Note**
>
> *If the Return Type is set to a simple
>   type*, Visual Basic or C# is not
>   automatically generated for the
>   Function Import.

Comment: The both languages are being generated function import in xml format but when I access those function by Data Entity class then it doesn't show function name.